# Why does `npm test` take so long on only one test?

Tags: reactjs, npm, jestjs, create-react-app, babel-jest

After `npx create-react-app my-app` I run `npm test` and I get the following:

```
 PASS  src/App.test.js
  ✓ renders learn react link (48ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.555s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

Why does it take `2.5s` to run the entire suite, but only `48ms` to run the test?
How can I speed up this process?
Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I'm running this computer:

[image]

Comment: Jest is very CPU intensive and requires quite a bit of RAM. If you have an older desktop/laptop, it's going to be slow (and get much, much, much slower if you add more tests). For example, I ran the same test on a high-end desktop and my test results are [noticeably quicker](https://i.imgur.com/FSgtiu1.png). That said, the tests should get cached and be somewhat quicker over multiple re-runs.

Comment: A lot of test framework setup and teardown. Of the framework itself, before all/before each/after all/after each on test blocks can also effect this. Generally though the bulk of time is spent on initializing the test suite.

Comment: @DrewReese is there a way to get this time down by skipping some steps or throwing away some features? I'm happy to throw away "watching" or nearly anything just to get the instant feedback

Comment: I've a project I'm involved in with 6500+ tests that takes around a minute to run (watcher or CI), each test taking milliseconds to run. This is the full test suite. Depending on configuration, with a watcher you may be able to live filter what tests you want to run. For example, when I'm developing a new module/component, I'll filter and run only the test file for the file I'm creating/working in. Periodically I'll run the full test suite to ensure I'm not introducing external issues inadvertently.

Comment: @DrewReese 
My project currently has 6 tests and it takes 8 seconds to run. Something must be wrong.

Comment: Perhaps better advice can be given if better question proposed. If you update question with your test code (any setup/configuration included) then we may be able to better see what is happening.

Comment: Without knowing how setup and tests look like it is hard to tell. Maybe there is something in the teardown waiting for something to close that you didn't close explicitly, so it waits for a timeout. Or something in the startup phase takes longer, or something completely different.

Comment: @DrewReese @t.niese @MattCarlotta 
The tests from the beginning are exactly what's packaged in `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: Yes but the timing you show in your question is not slow or unexpected, here it is 20ms for the test and ~1sec total, so given set my setup is roughly twice as fast as yours. But you say `My project currently has 6 tests and it takes 8 seconds to run.`, so you added some own tests, for each of them an elapsed time should be reported. For those test you should check of them are unexpected slow, because if they would take 40ms each, it would not explain the increase from 2 to 8 seconds.

Comment: You've definitely added some tests of your own. As a sanity check I've just `npx create-react-app my-app`, `cd my-app/`, `npm i`, then `npm test` and there are no tests.

Comment: @DrewReese  I've found you need to select 'a' to run all the tests again after you run `npm test`.  Then it finds the default test.

Comment: @TygerTy Ah, thanks. For reference this took 3.039s, 1.82s, then all subsequent runs ~0.1-0.2s to execute, on my machine(MBP 2018, 2.2GHz i7, 16GB). When I kill the watcher and again `npm test`, I see the same, first run 2-3s, second about half that, then all after ~0.1-0.2s. @libby can you provide more context on what your tests are doing?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is pretty simple: if your test takes 48ms and the entire duration of the suite takes 2.555 seconds, then there is other code that being run that eats up the other 2.507 seconds.

In other words, the code that has to run before and after this one test is significantly more than what you see without looking at the `jest` library's framework code.

That's why the runtime of the suite is longer (2.5s) than the sum of the tests (48ms).

---

To make the testing simpler (as well as easier) and more automatic there is a lot of "behind the scenes" code that is allowing you to:

- write your tests the way you are, i.e. in a way that is easy to understand/write, but not necessarily how the compiler will actually see it; it will be compiled to something else
- find your files that are needed for each test; it takes some time to get all the specified files together
- compile the specified files (e.g. using webpack) to what you've specified in your build,
- build/compile a testing environment to run your code in, as `jest` emulates a browser to keep your code similar to what it would run on in production
- run a test
- then output the results

---

An analogy to compare it to would be renting a ride-share; you have a minimum cost to just get in the car, but once you are there it is that plus a per-minute or per-mile cost. So, it costs you $2.507 to just rent a bike plus 4.8 cents a mile.

---

Once your testing environment is made at the beginning, your subsequent tests will not each require 2.5 seconds to run.

Useful links for jest related to time:

- [Setup and Teardown for Tests](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown#order-of-execution-of-describe-and-test-blocks)
- [Jest-Webpack setup](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack)
- [Caching Issues with Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#caching-issues)
- [Jest Architecture](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/architecture)
- [Memory Leakage](https://chanind.github.io/javascript/2019/10/12/jest-tests-memory-leak.html)

---

Ways that you can speed up your tests is to:

- make sure your webpack/babel is configured for jest properly,
- you use setup-teardown in an intelligent manner,
- (optional/selective) you could run your tests in [node rather than jest's default `jsdom` environment](https://medium.com/@kevinsimper/how-to-disable-jsdom-in-jest-make-jest-run-twice-as-fast-a01193f23405).  Although the downside is your React tests will fail, so this only works with Node-only tests (server side).
- Lookup how to write efficient tests, as optimized test code make a difference, here is one such article that [provides some insight](https://jestjs.io/blog/2016/03/11/javascript-unit-testing-performance.html).

---

Another non-code option is to use a better/faster CPU or use a more efficient operating system.

Your 2.555s with the default create-react-app is multitudes faster compared to my 6.17s on a Windows 10, Asus GL502VMK.

Running it on a Ubuntu 20 Desktop VM (Virtualbox on the same Windows 10 machine mentioned above, 8 out of the 12GB Host's RAM, 4 out of the 8 Host's CPUs), it takes 2.105s.

---

You can find a lot of articles complaining about Jest and the execution time, so it doesn't seem that this is necessarily just you.  There are parts of Jest that are just not fast.

Comment: Yea, except they do take that long if not longer.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "tests" when you say, "they."   Is your question then why are the timings of the suite not a sum of the test times?  I got the impression you were asking where is the rest of the time going.

Comment: Well after I run the tests and then run them again nothing gets any better and sometimes it just gets worse

Comment: There a number of possible factors.  For one, your suite cache is rebuilt every run, so the suite itself has the benefit of a cache, as I understand each suite is intended to build it's own modules as to help avoid problems that could arise with modifying modules.  So outside of modifying the tests with better design towards time, then yeah, I wouldn't really expect better results.  As for getting worse, it could attributed towards CPU load at the time you run a test.  Get a better CPU and test times will drop.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add the `--maxWorkers=4` flag and saw a speed increase

Without the flag

```
 PASS  src/organization/organization.service.spec.ts (6.039 s)
 PASS  src/test/test.controller.spec.ts (6.318 s)
 PASS  src/test-suite/test-suite.controller.spec.ts (6.33 s)
 PASS  src/organization/organization.controller.spec.ts (6.593 s)
 PASS  src/test-suite/test-suite.service.spec.ts

Test Suites: 3 skipped, 5 passed, 5 of 8 total
Tests:       7 skipped, 23 passed, 30 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.128 s
```

With `--maxWorkers=4` added

```
 PASS  src/test/test.controller.spec.ts (5.364 s)
 PASS  src/organization/organization.controller.spec.ts (5.446 s)
 PASS  src/organization/organization.service.spec.ts
 PASS  src/test-suite/test-suite.controller.spec.ts
 PASS  src/test-suite/test-suite.service.spec.ts

Test Suites: 3 skipped, 5 passed, 5 of 8 total
Tests:       7 skipped, 23 passed, 30 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.139 s
```

Although it seems to vary pretty wildly as tests are run. It's still pretty insane that it takes this long. I am used to working with Jasmine/Karma tests on in Angular projects which run pretty quickly.  I can run several hundred tests in the time it takes for Jest to setup `expect(true).toEqual(true)`